# Webhooks plus recurring payments

Tags: paypal

Do the web-hook events catch the payments done through the recurring payment setup ?

Will the 'Payment sale completed' event be fired when a recurring payment is successfully completed at the start of a month ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal will inform you only in two cases - when create a recurring payment and when the user canceled this recurring. Recurring transactions will occur as you set in the parameters with which you create this recurring profile.

I recommended use a paypal express checkout and method CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. In this case the recurring payment is created fast and paypal return the result immediately. Other way is to post parameters with standard html form, and check IPN result

Comment: Thanks . I will take your word on this and move ahead.

Comment: Hi Pavel, one related query.If I issue a refund against the recurring payment that I have setup, then will I be able to catch a Payment refunded event in the web hook (I am issuing a refund from the paypal interface by logging in to my paypal account). I tried this out , I was able to catch the Payment refund event for normal payments that were done. But for recurring payments when I issued a refund the event was not fired. From what I understand refund is a separate call all together then shouldn't it get fired for recurring payments as well ? If no then how should I handle the refunds ?